# Why do my pics look slightly fuzzy and when I click to enlarge become clear

Tags: css

I have a site with adverts. Each ad has a pic. Each image looks slightly fuzzy but when I click to enlarge they become clearer.

Any way to fix this with css? Same problem across all browsers.

```
meta property="og:image" 
content="https://adsler.co.uk/wp- 
content/uploads/awpcp/images/19808423-2b60d824- 
large.jpg">
<link rel="image_src" href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp- 
content/uploads/awpcp/images/19808423-2b60d824- 
large.jpg">
<!-- END - Another WordPress Classifieds Plugin Open 
Graph meta tags -->
<link rel="icon" href="https://adsler.co.uk/wp- 
content/uploads/2018/12/cropped-Adsler_final-01-1-
```

100x100.jpg" sizes="32x32" />

Comment: Can you please share any code snippet for more clarifications. Thanks

Comment: Not sure if this is relevant but please see above

Comment: No it's not helping out. It's your code deployed on any server ? Then share your site link. Thanks

Comment: Https://www.adsler.co.uk

Comment: Thank you for the link, where i find the images which have the issue.

Comment: https://adsler.co.uk/wp-user-test-dashboard-2/awpcp-show-ad/22/nicos-cleaning-service/london/uk/westminster/business-advert/

Comment: For example. Definitely a problem in mobile view. Think so on desktop too.

Comment: Thank you for more clarifications.

Comment: Thank you for looking. So any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is appeared because of different images paths. Your **Nico's Cleaning Service NCS** image get thumbnail image path.

```
https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/awpcp/thumbs/flyermaker_15032019_134523-ac957ffd-primary.png
```

and when we **click to enlarge image** the image become clear in modal because it show large size image.

```
https://adsler.co.uk/wp-content/uploads/awpcp/images/flyermaker_15032019_134523-ac957ffd-large.png
```

To resolve fuzzy behavior you have to use **large size image** in both side. Thanks

Comment: You just need to change image path in product page. Thanks